# programmatically open 'system properties'

Tags: windows, properties, windows-xp, system

How can I open the various windows in system properties from command line or using VBS or JS?
By this I mean windows such as User Profiles, environment variables, performance options, DEP, hardware profiles, windows update settings, remote desktop settings, etc I am using windows XP but it wont let me create a shortcut to these dialogs. Sysdm.cpl cant do it either it seems.
System properties is the window that opnes when you right click my computer and hit properties.

Answer (score 0):

One way to open the edit environment variables of the windows through the command line would be to call the run.exe:

> "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables

So there must be something similar for other windows.

You can also open a specific tab of the system properties window by using the control command and the tab number:

> control sysdm.cpl,,3